# Disable log out when turning off the screen

Tags: 21.04, displayport, fluxbox

I'm using **Ubuntu 21.04** with **Fluxbox** as my Window Manager.
My screen is connected via **DisplayPort**.

The screen has multiple input ports and I often switch between different connected devices or sometimes turn it off.

Whenever my Ubuntu machine is **disconnected from the screen** - either by switching to a differen source or turning it off - **my graphical session is terminated** and I'm logged out.

This is *very annoying* and I want do disable this behaviour.

- I've tried adding `xset s off -dpms` to my `.fluxbox/startup` config but it doesn't seem to help.
- Also I've tried using `gnome-tweaks` to disable energy saving mode when closing the lid.

**Q**: How can I stop Ubuntu from logging me out when disconnecting my monitor?

*Note: I'm pretty sure this started only happening after upgrading to 21.04.*

Comment: Perhaps fluxbox/Xorg is crashing, and you are being returned to the login screen? Are there any files in `/var/crash`?